# Can I alias all directory requests to a single file in nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect, alias, mime-type, json

I'm trying to figure out how to take all requests made to a particular directory and return a json string without a redirect, in nginx.

**Example:**

```
curl -i http://example.com/api/call1/
```

Expected result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 13 Apr 2012 23:48:21 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 13 Apr 2012 22:58:56 GMT
Server: nginx
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Content-Length: 38
Connection: keep-alive

{"logout": true}
```

**Here's what I have so far in my nginx conf:**

```
location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
    index /api_logout.json;
    alias /path/to/file/api_logout.json;
    types { }
    default_type "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    break;
}
```

However, when I try to make the request the Content-Type doesn't stick:

```
$ curl -i http://example.com/api/call1/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Fri, 13 Apr 2012 23:48:21 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 13 Apr 2012 22:58:56 GMT
Server: nginx
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Content-Length: 38
Connection: keep-alive

{"logout": true}
```

Is there a better way to do this? How can I get the application/json type to stick?

**EDIT: Solution!**

I figured out you can just send manual strings in the return statement, so I did that instead of using aliases!

Final code I used:

```
location /api {
    types { }
    default_type "application/json";
    return 200 "{\"logout\" : true"}";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a rewrite instead to get the catchall behaviour.

```
location /logout.json {
    alias /tmp/logout.json;
    types {
        application/json json;
    }
}
rewrite ^/api/.* /logout.json;
```

Comment: Doesn't this redirect you to /logout.json? I'm trying to avoid sending a 302 redirect response.

Comment: No, that's an internal [rewrite](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite). Redirects are only sent if an absolute location is specified or a `redirect` or `permanent` flag is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. The whole configuration could be:

```
# default.conf
# Add file here: /etc/nginx/html/logout.json

server {
  listen 80;
  rewrite ^.*$ /logout.json last;
}
```